# How can I record on a different octave then what is transposed on Yamaha E363

Tags: recording

I want to be able to record a piece of this song that is outside the 5 octave length of the keyboard. The idea I had was to record the section I can't play and transpose it but that transposes everything along with it

Comment: I just left an answer, but then realized a clarification is needed. Are you transposing the keys on the keyboard or the recorded result?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method #1

The [E363 manual](https://jp.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/7/890277/psre363_en_om_b0.pdf) (page 45) explains how to transpose the keyboard pitches, which can be done up to one octave.

1. Press the FUNCTION button until TRANSPOSE appears.
2. Enter 12 (directly or using the + button) on the number pad to raise the keyboard an octave.

So you would record up to the point needed, transpose, record the high part, transpose back, and finish recording.

#### Method #2

If that fails, and the range of the song allows, record the entire piece one octave too low, then raise transpose the entire recording up one octave.